# How to create Zend submodule w/ proper routes

Tags: zend-framework, routes

I am in the process of creating a system that will be consumed by hundreds of apps.  The system is built into different modules that handle different types of data each with its own admin, web and api controllers.

The system is getting rather large and I am looking to organize each of these modules into submodules, specifically the api which for uri purposes all actions are in a single api resource.

This is obviously bad since action names are getting to obscure as the list of actions increase.

I can't find any reference on how to create submodules in Zend. I have listed below how I would like the structure to be

Currently:

```
- /application
  - /moduleA
    - /controllers
      - controller1
      - controller2
      - controller3 (restful API resource)
  - /moduleB
    - /controllers
      - controller1
      - controller2
      - controller3 (restful API resource)
  - /moduleC
    - /controllers
      - controller1
      - controller2
      - controller3 (restful API resource)
```

I would like...

```
- /application
  - /moduleA
    - /controllers
      - controller1
      - controller2
      - /submoduleAPI
        - controller3 (restful API resource)
  - /moduleB
    - /controllers
      - controller1
      - controller2
      - /submoduleAPI
        - controller3 (restful API resource)
  - /moduleC
    - /controllers
      - controller1
      - controller2
      /submoduleAPI
        - controller3 (restful API resource)
```

The routes should end up being for other resources

```
/:module/:resource/<:id>
```

and for API

```
/:module/api/:resource/<:id>
```

Comment: Have a look at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.default-routes

    $ctrl->setControllerDirectory(
    array(
        'submoduleAPI' => '/ModuleA/controllers/submoduleAPI'

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution that made you happy?

Comment: I can't remember now but I think I did. It wasn't a submodule solution though. I may have made a plugin just did a different response based on content type headers.

Either way, I've been doing some development in Rails and Django and they seem much more flexible with routes. Maybe ZF2 has made some improvements?